# How to remove 0s from start of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My Arraylist(sample) contains:
A : [ 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 4, 8, 8, 2 ]

I want to remove all the 0s that appear at start of the list.
Expected answer:
A : [ 6, 0, 6, 4, 8, 8, 2 ]

I'm trying:

```
for(i=0; i<A.size(); i++){
    if(A.get(i) == 0)
        A.remove(i);
    else break;
}
```

My output:
A : [6, 6, 4, 8, 8, 2]

I believe while performing A.remove() operation the indexes shift thus when the loop runs for the second time the index of second zero becomes 1(previously 2) and thus it also is removed.

What alternative should i use?

Comment: 1)find index of last prefix 0 2) `sublist`.

Comment: The overwhelming convention in Java is that local variables and instance fields (sometimes called instance variables) start with a lower-case letter. So `a` rather than `A` if it's an instance of `ArrayList`. Sticking to the standard conventions is useful when asking for help because it makes it easier for people to understand your code. (It's a good idea in any case.)

Comment: Did you try using Iterator? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `i` will increase at the same time you've removed an item from the beginning. So on the second loop you're looking at index 1, but index 0 now  has a value you've never looked at. It would work for your examle because there's only one 0 at the beginning, but would fail with `[0, 0, 6, 0]`.

Instead, use `while` and only look at index `0`:

```
while (A.size() > 0 && A.get(0) == 0) {
    A.remove(0);
}
```